# Yarn is resolving packages from my locale registry instead of official yarn

Tags: node.js, registry, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

After `yarn add LIB` in my `yarn.lock` file is generated "resolved" url like:

```
figures@^2.0.0:
  version "2.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.mycompanyurl.com/figures/-/figures-2.0.0.tgz#3ab1a2d2a62c8bfb431a0c94cb797a2fce27c962"
  integrity sha1-OrGi0qYsi/tDGgyUy3l6L84nyWI=
  dependencies:
    escape-string-regexp "^1.0.5"
```

but I would like to use default "resolved" url:

```
figures@^2.0.0:
  version "2.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/figures/-/figures-2.0.0.tgz#3ab1a2d2a62c8bfb431a0c94cb797a2fce27c962"
  integrity sha1-OrGi0qYsi/tDGgyUy3l6L84nyWI=
  dependencies:
    escape-string-regexp "^1.0.5"
```

How can I specify yarn "resolved" registry in some config file? I would like to push this config into my repositry.

I am using

```
yarn -v
1.22.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add .yarnrc file to your repository that points to your own registry:

```
registry "https://registry.mycompanyurl.com/"
```